# Failed to initialize Flutter engine: error 2 (MacOS Ventura?)

Tags: flutter, macos, dart, macos-ventura

After updating to macOS 13 (Ventura) I get `Failed to initialize Flutter engine: error 2` when trying run the macOS version.

Here is the full log:

```
2 warnings generated.
2022-11-08 11:52:15.742 ibtoold[36004:455401] NSFileCoordinator is doing nothing.
/* com.apple.actool.document.warnings */
/Users/pascalgehring/Developer/deescus-app/macos/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/(null)[2d][app_icon_1024.png]: warning: The app icon set "AppIcon" has 7 unassigned children.
/Users/pascalgehring/Developer/deescus-app/macos/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/(null)[2d][app_icon_1024.png]: warning: The app icon set "AppIcon" has 7 unassigned children.
/* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
/Users/pascalgehring/Developer/deescus-app/build/macos/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug/Runner.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist
/Users/pascalgehring/Developer/deescus-app/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/deescus.app/Contents/Resources/AppIcon.icns
/Users/pascalgehring/Developer/deescus-app/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/deescus.app/Contents/Resources/Assets.car

warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Libuv-gRPC' from project 'Pods')
warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
/Users/pascalgehring/Developer/deescus-app/macos/Runner.xcodeproj: warning: The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.12, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.13 to 13.0.99. (in target 'Flutter Assemble' from project 'Runner')
warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Flutter Assemble' from project 'Runner')
```